# Referencing the count in object PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to reference `COUNT(*)` from the object below. I grab the date using `$the_date = $obj2->the_date` as per the below example, but how do I reference `count`? Of course using `COUNT(*)` will throw an error.

```
object(stdClass)[358]
  public 'COUNT(*)' => string '36' (length=2)
  public 'the_date' => string '2019-08-29' (length=10)
```

Comment: `$obj2->{'COUNT(*)'}`

Comment: Strictly speaking you can set the property name to a string `$propName = 'count(*)';` then access your object with it `$yourInstance->$propName; // 36` but this is horrendous and you should alias it as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *alias* the concerned column in the resultset of the query, like:

```
SELECT the_date, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM ...
```

Then:

```
object(stdClass)[358]
  public 'cnt' => string '36' (length=2)
  public 'the_date' => string '2019-08-29' (length=10)
```

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I didn't think of this before. This I hadn't seen before. Learn something every day.